# Processor (version 9.5) reports xsl:result as unknown element

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

Does anybody know why the following stylesheet receives compilation errors when processed by Saxon 9.5?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="http://www.test.com"
>
  <xsl:variable name="lowerCaseLetters" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="upperCaseLetters" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="notAllowedCharactersInTelNumber" select="concat($lowerCaseLetters, $upperCaseLetters, '.:')" />

  <xsl:function name="my:isTelNumberValid">
    <xsl:param name="number" />
    <xsl:result
      type="xs:boolean"
      select="string-length($number) = string-length(translate($number, $notAllowedCharactersInTelNumber, ''))" />
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The error I am getting is:

`Error at xsl:result on line 13 column 115 of testXslResult.xsl: XTSE0010: Unknown XSLT element: result`

`Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.`

According to the [documentation](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.4/xsl-elements.html#xsl%3afunction) the syntax of my function should be correct.

Comment: You are looking at old documentation. Early drafts of the XSLT 2.0 spec had an `xsl:result` element, but it was dropped: http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-xslt20-20030502/#changes-in-this-draft

Comment: Sadly Google isn't smart enough to distinguish current information from obsolete information. Use it with more care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSLT 2.0 language does not have an `xsl:result` element, simply use

`<xsl:sequence select="string-length($number) = string-length(translate($number, $notAllowedCharactersInTelNumber, ''))" />`

inside the function body to return the result.

Comment: What a bummer. Should not it be backwards compatible?

Comment: I think that the XSLT 2.0 recommendation released in 2007 and first implemented by Saxon version 8.9 never had an `xsl:result` element, nor did XSLT 1.0 have any such feature, therefore I doubt that Saxon 8.9 or later ever tried to implement such an element. During the development of XSLT 2.0 I think that Saxon always tried to implement the current draft but never tried to be backwards compatible with outdated drafts.

Comment: The documentation you cited was for Saxon 7.4, which is 21 major releases ago. No doubt Saxon 7.4 indeed had such an element, and no doubt that's what it was called for a short time during the development of the spec. Saxon has always implemented draft specs as soon as it could, and the policy has always been to change the product if the W3C spec changes. You use features in a draft spec at your peril; you use obsolete versions of the documentation at even greater peril.